# How to resolve ResourceNotFoundException on splash screen in android

Tags: android

I working on splash screen. It going to crash on SDK-2.3 and SDK-4.2 can anybody help me what is going wrong.

Java Code: My java code like:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    }
}
```

Splash.xml: This is my splash screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/splash">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Exception: I am getting exception like:

```
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.multicom.techlink.app/com.multicom.techlink.app.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.multicom.techlink.app.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:20)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     ... 11 more
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     ... 23 more
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02007d a=-1 r=0x7f02007d}
01-28 07:24:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):
```

Comment: upload your java code

Comment: do you have a image by name splash in drawable folder? or is it `splash.xml`?

Comment: Please post `drawable/splash.xml`

Comment: Please post /res/drawable/splash (it can be an xml file, or a png, or a patch 9 png). Most likely, it isn't there, or there is a typo in the way it's being referenced.